# Why does this branch data hazard happen during the instruction decode stage?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines, mips

Suppose I have the following MIPS code on a CPU with forwarding enabled:

```
L1: LW   R2    0(R1)
    ADDI R2    R2    2
    SW   R2    0(R1) 
    ADDI R1    R1    8
    SUB  R4    R1    R3
    BNEZ R4    L1
```

The last two lines are of importance for me.

My intuition is that the output to `R4` is calculated during the `EX` stage of the pipeline, and should be ready in time for the `BNEZ` instruction to `EX` in the next cycle. However, I'm getting this output from WinMIPS64:

[image: WinMIPS output]

Why is there a hazard during the `ID` stage? Forwarding is enabled, so it ought to know `R4` will be available at the next stage of the pipeline, when it needs to evaluate if `R4 == 0`, but it still adds a bubble.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MIPS pipeline, for branches and jumps, all of the arithmetic is done in the instruction decode portion of the pipeline. See this [MIPS handbook](https://www.brunel.ac.uk/%7Eeestppk/EE5531/06MIPSPipeline.pdf) pg. 9, or this handy [UCSD ppt.](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi02/cse141/c14branchHazard.pdf) explaining the rationale for this design choice on slide 14.

It used to be the case that all of that stuff would happen during the `EXE` stage, and the program counter would be updated in the `MEM` stage; however, by adding hardware to evaluate those things during the `ID` stage, an incorrect branch prediction only comes with a 1 cycle penalty.

See the difference visualized here:

Evaluating the condition during `EXE` and updating the `PC` during `MEM`:
[image: 3 stalls]

Vs. Evaluating the condition and updating the `PC`during `ID`
[image: 1 stall]

Thus, in my original question, the reason there's a RAW hazard during the `ID` stage is because the `R4` operand isn't ready in time to be evaluated during the `ID` stage. Using the old architecture, the hazard would be avoided, but an incorrect branch prediction would result in a far worse stall.